# My useState hook isn't working in a specific portion of my code, but it's working everywhere else. Why is this happening despite using identical code?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I've used the useState() hook throughout my project for form management. It was always working as intended. However, in a RoleEditCard component, I've been unable to use the useState hook at all.

If I do this:

```
    const [roleName, setRoleName] = useState(props.roleInfo.role_name);
    console.log(roleName, props.roleInfo.role_name);
```

I get the following in the console:
`undefined New Role`
With "New Role" being the expected value of both variables. What's the issue?

My full code (Here, only reactjs and react-bootstrap have been used):

```
// Here, we handle the form for adding new role.

// Package imports
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// import { Multiselect } from 'multiselect-react-dropdown';

// React Bootstrap components import
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { FaTimes, FaCheck } from 'react-icons/fa';

// CSS Module imports
import classes from './RoleEditCard.module.css';

const RoleEditCard = (props) => {
    // State handling
    const [roleName, setRoleName] = useState(props.roleInfo.role_name);
    const [roleDescription, setRoleDescription] = useState(props.roleInfo.role_description);
    const [rolePrivileges, setRolePrivileges] = useState([...props.privilegeInfo]);
    const [roleInfo, setRoleInfo] = useState({...props.roleInfo});
    console.log(roleInfo, props.roleInfo);

    // Handle submission of form
    const submitHandler = event => {
        if (roleName !== props.role.role_name || roleDescription !== props.role.role_description || JSON.stringify(rolePrivileges) !== JSON.stringify(props.role.role_privileges)) {
            // Send details to container
            props.onSubmission({
                roleName: roleName,
                roleDescription: roleDescription,
                rolePrivileges: rolePrivileges.map(optionObject => optionObject.sub_menu_name)
            });
        } else {
            console.log("NO CHANGES!");
        }
        // Prevent page reload
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    const resetHandler = event => {
        setRoleName("");
        setRoleDescription("");
        setRolePrivileges([]);
        // Prevent page reload
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
        <Container className={classes.PageContents}>
            <Row>
                <Col sm={{ span: '8', offset: '2' }}>
                    <Card className={classes.editCard}>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                                <Form.Row className='text-left'>
                                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formRoleName" md='6'>
                                        <Form.Label>Role Name:</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control 
                                            placeholder="Role Name" 
                                            value={roleInfo.role_name} 
                                            required
                                            onChange={event => { setRoleInfo({ ...roleInfo, role_name: event.target.value })}} 
                                        />
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Form.Row>

                                <Form.Row className='text-left'>
                                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formRoleDescription" md='12'>
                                        <Form.Label>Description:</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control 
                                            type='textarea' 
                                            placeholder="Describe the Role" 
                                            value={roleDescription} 
                                            required
                                            onChange={event => { setRoleDescription(event.target.value) }}
                                        />
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Form.Row>

                                {/* Privilege Selection */}
                                <Form.Row className='text-left'>
                                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId='formPrivilege'>
                                        <Form.Label>Select Privileges</Form.Label>
                                        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
                                            {props.privileges.map((mainmenu, index) => (
                                                <Card key={mainmenu.id}>
                                                    <Card.Header>
                                                        <Row>
                                                            <Accordion.Toggle as={Col} variant="link" eventKey={mainmenu.id}>
                                                                {mainmenu.main_menu_name}
                                                            </Accordion.Toggle>
                                                        </Row>
                                                    </Card.Header>
                                                    { mainmenu.Sub_Menus.length ? (
                                                        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={mainmenu.id}>
                                                            <Card.Body>
                                                                {mainmenu.Sub_Menus.map(submenu => (
                                                                    <Form.Check
                                                                        type='checkbox'
                                                                        value={submenu.sub_menu_name}
                                                                        key={submenu.sub_menu_name}
                                                                        defaultChecked={props.originalPrivileges.indexOf(submenu.sub_menu_name) !== -1}
                                                                        onClick={event => {
                                                                            const curVal = event.target.value;
                                                                            const privList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rolePrivileges));
                                                                            if (privList.indexOf(curVal) !== -1) {
                                                                                privList.splice(privList.indexOf(curVal), 1);
                                                                            } else {
                                                                                privList.push(curVal);
                                                                            }
                                                                            setRolePrivileges(privList);
                                                                        }}
                                                                        label={submenu.sub_menu_name}
                                                                    />
                                                                ))}
                                                            </Card.Body>
                                                        </Accordion.Collapse>
                                                    ) : null}
                                                </Card>
                                            ))}
                                        </Accordion>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Form.Row>

                                <Form.Row className='justify-content-md-center'>
                                    <Col md='auto'>
                                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className={classes.FormButton}>
                                            <FaCheck color='white' height='24' /> Submit
                                        </Button>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col md='auto'></Col>
                                    <Col md='auto'>
                                        <Button variant="danger" type="button" className={classes.FormButton} onClick={resetHandler}>
                                            <FaTimes color='white' height='24' /> Reset
                                        </Button>
                                    </Col>
                                </Form.Row>
                            </Form>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default RoleEditCard
```

This how I've called RoleEditCard:

```
                    <RoleEditCard
                        onSubmission={this.submitHandler}
                        roleInfo={this.state.roleDetails}
                        privilegeInfo={this.state.privilegeDetails}
                        originalPrivileges={this.state.originalPrivileges}
                        privileges={this.state.records}
                    />
```

Note: The roleDetails, privilegeDetails, etc. were defined in ComponentDidMount() of a class component.

Additionally, I've used similar useState code in a UserEditCard as well:

```
// Package import
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// Bootstrap Components
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { FaTimes, FaCheck } from 'react-icons/fa';

// CSS Modules
import classes from './UserEditCard.module.css';

const UserEditCard = (props) => {
    const [fullName, setFullName] = useState(props.UserInfo.full_name);
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState(props.UserInfo.phone_number);
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(props.UserInfo.status);

    const submitHandler = event => {
        //this.onSubmission
        if (fullName !== props.UserInfo.full_name || phoneNumber !== props.UserInfo.phone_number || status !== props.UserInfo.status) {
            props.onSubmission({
                fullName: fullName,
                phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                status: status
            });
        } else {
            console.log("NO CHANGE!");
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    const resetHandler = event => {
        setFullName(props.UserInfo.full_name);
        setPhoneNumber(props.UserInfo.phone_number);
        setStatus(props.UserInfo.status);
        // Prevent page reload
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
        <Container className={classes.PageContents}>
            <Row>
                <Col sm={{ span: '8', offset: '2' }}>
                    <Card className={classes.editCard}>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>

                                <Form.Row className='text-left'>
                                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formFullName" md='6'>
                                        <Form.Label>Full Name:</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            value={fullName}
                                            placeholder="Full Name"
                                            required
                                            onChange={event => {
                                                setFullName(event.target.value);
                                            }}
                                        />
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Form.Row>

                                <Form.Row className='text-left'>
                                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formEmailId" md='6'>
                                        <Form.Label>Email Address:</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            value={props.UserInfo.email_id}
                                            disabled
                                        />
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formPhoneNumber" md='6'>
                                        <Form.Label>Phone Number:</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            placeholder="1234567890"
                                            value={phoneNumber}
                                            required
                                            // May start with plus; cannot end with whitespace; maximum length of 20 characters
                                            pattern='^(?=\+?\d+( ?\d+)*$).{1,20}$'
                                            onChange={event => {
                                                setPhoneNumber(event.target.value);
                                            }}
                                        />
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Form.Row>

                                <Form.Row className='text-left'>
                                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formRoleSelect">
                                        <Form.Label>Role</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            as="select"
                                            value={props.UserInfo.role_name}
                                            disabled
                                        >
                                            <option value={props.UserInfo.role_name}>{props.UserInfo.role_name}</option>
                                            {/* Company List */}
                                            {/* {props.roleOptions.map(role => <option value={role} key={role}>{role}</option>)} */}
                                        </Form.Control>
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                        <Form.Label>Status</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            as="select"
                                            value={status}
                                            onChange={event => {
                                                setStatus(event.target.value);
                                            }}
                                            required
                                        >
                                            <option value='Active'>Active</option>
                                            <option value='Inactive'>Inactive</option>
                                            <option value='Deleted'>Deleted</option>
                                        </Form.Control>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Form.Row>

                                <Form.Row className='justify-content-md-center'>
                                    <Col md='auto'>
                                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className={classes.FormButton}>
                                            <FaCheck color='white' height='24' /> Submit
                                        </Button>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col md='auto'></Col>
                                    <Col md='auto'>
                                        <Button variant="danger" type="button" className={classes.FormButton} onClick={resetHandler}>
                                            <FaTimes color='white' height='24' /> Reset
                                        </Button>
                                    </Col>
                                </Form.Row>
                            </Form>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default UserEditCard
```

Comment: Try printing that state inside an useEffect when the component is rendered `useEffect(() => console.log(roleInfo, props.roleInfo), [])`. It's probably undefined because the props were not passed to your component `RoleEditCard` yet

Comment: This is impossible to answer without you showing us how you use `<RoleEditCard ... />`.

Comment: Do you asynchronously fetch `roleInfo` from a remote resource? Do you see another log before that log with both values `undefined`? Note that the initial value to `useState` is only set once on mount so if it is `undefined` on mount but later changes to some value you will not see this reflected in the state as long as you do not explicitly update it with the new value.

Comment: Try logging like this: `console.log('rendering',JSON.stringify(roleInfo), JSON.stringify(props.roleInfo));` How many times does it log and what does it log?

Comment: *Note: The roleDetails, privilegeDetails, etc. were defined in ComponentDidMount() of a class component*. Your parent `componentDidMount` is only called **after** your child mounts and at that point the initial state will already be set. This is why you see it as `undefined`. So the `useState` hook is working correctly. But if your parent actually manages all that data your component should likely be controlled and not have own state at all. It can receive everything as props and call handlers passed to it.

Comment: The solution provided by Piyush Rana/Nicolas Hevia worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something else inside useState like

```
 const [roleName, setRoleName] = useState("Hello");
```

see if **console.log** printing roleName **`"Hello"`** and if yes simply put this to fix your state:

```
const role = props.roleInfo.role_name;
useEffect(() => setRoleName(role), [role]);
```